# ExtJS Gridfilter values to PHP

Tags: php, extjs, filter, grid

I'm using ExtJS v2.0 . I would like to grab the `gridfilter` values and pass them to a PHP page as `$_POST`, `$_GET`, `$variable` or any possible method that would work to be inserted in PHP query using this backend code: http://www.vinylfox.com/grid-filter-php-backend-code/

I will use those queryes to print one table with the results and format for print.

Any ideas ?

Comment: That code looks like a) it depends on register_globals, and b) would be vulnerable to SQL injection, so I would be careful using it.

Comment: What would I have to change or add to be invulnerable to SQL injections ? Thanks

Comment: Generally speaking, using parameterized queries / prepared statements, such as PDO provides (see php.net/PDO) is the best method for preventing SQL injection - however, just passing user-supplied data through mysql_real_escape_string() is a big step forward if you don't want to rewrite your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GridFilter reloads the store with some search parameters, e.g.:

> filter[0][data][type] = string
>   filter[0][data][value] = some value
>   filter[0][field] = company

These data will typically end up in PHP in $_POST. So you should analyse these values and create an SQL statement. Like mentioned in the comments, you should quote the values.